# Running weld osgi example with felix on java se

Tags: java, osgi, cdi, apache-felix, weld

I want to do the following solution:Apache Felix + Weld 2.2.10.SP1 for Java SE. For that I want to run one of examples from weld archive - weld-osgi-paint.

I use felix 4.6.1, java8 and I have the following bundles which I install and start:

```
cdi-api.jar
javax.annotation-api-1.2.jar
javax.el-api-2.2.4.jar
javax.interceptor-api-1.2.jar
log4j-1.2.17.jar
ops4j-base-lang-1.5.0.jar
org.apache.felix.scr-1.8.2.jar
org.apache.servicemix.bundles.javax-inject-1_2.jar
org.osgi.compendium-4.3.1.jar
pax-cdi-api-0.8.0.jar
pax-cdi-extender-0.8.0.jar
pax-cdi-extension-0.8.0.jar
pax-cdi-spi-0.8.0.jar
pax-swissbox-core-1.8.0.jar
pax-swissbox-lifecycle-1.8.0.jar
pax-swissbox-tracker-1.8.0.jar
slf4j-api-1.7.6.jar
slf4j-log4j12-1.7.2.jar
weld-osgi-paint-api.jar
weld-osgi-paint-core.jar
weld-osgi-paint-square.jar
weld-osgi-paint-triangle.jar
weld-se-core.jar
weld-se.jar
xbean-bundleutils-3.18.jar
```

Besides I have the following extra packages

```
String SYSTEM_PACKAGES =
        "org.osgi.framework;version=\"1.8\"," +
        "org.osgi.service.packageadmin;version=\"1.8\","+
        "org.osgi.framework.wiring;version=\"1.8\","+
        "javax.swing,javax.management,javax.naming,javax.xml.parsers,"+
        "org.w3c.dom,org.xml.sax,org.xml.sax.helpers";
configMap.put(Constants.FRAMEWORK_SYSTEMPACKAGES, SYSTEM_PACKAGES);
```

I run the program and this is what I get

> org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Fragment bundles can not be
>   started.
>       at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:1981)
>       at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:977)
>       at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:964)

And nothing more. What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the bundles you try to start is a fragment. Fragment bundles may not be started. They can only be resolved.